# Drupal 7 и таксономия

Tags: drupal

Приветствую, помогите разобраться с проблемой.
Категории для статей создаются с помощью таксономии.

Как было : Имя термина - body, синоним урл - body.
Путь у нод sitename.com/body/nodetitle.

Переходим  по ссылке sitename.com/body - видим все статьи, к которым относится термин, но заголовок "Body".  Для русского сайта не годится.

Поменял имя термина "Уход за телом", синоним урл оставил body. теперь при генерации статьи получаю sitename/uhod-za-telom/nodetitle, а нужно sitename.com/body/nodetitle.
Токен [term:url], в пазавто, для материала использовать нельзя.
Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить синоним sitename/uhod-za-telom -> sitename/Уход за телом и поставить Global Redirect, чтобы избавиться от дублей.

Comment: Решил токен добавить модулем, взял за основу http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/418
Всё аналогично, кроме 
$replacements[$original] = $node->field_category['und'][0]['tid'];

Проблема в том, что токен появился, но значение не подставляется. Я понимаю, что нужно получить алиас урл термина, но не пойму, как дебажить этот модуль. 
Вы бы могли подсказать в этом направлении?

Comment: Мне кажетмя вы сильно заморачиваетесь. Самый простой метод, добавить ещё один синоним конкретно для нужной категории вместо того,чтобы писать дополнительный модуль. 
А вообще вам нужно сперва загрузить саму ноду, а потом уже к ней подставлять алиас. Попробуйте примерно так $replacements[$original] =    node_load(arg(1))->field_category_name['und'][0]['tid'];

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите этот модуль: https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto
Он позволяет задавать правила для автоматического создания синонимов url.
Задавать правила можно нодам, терминам таксономии и д.р.